# Can I update metadata only with updatedocument API?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I'd like to update document's metadata only without re-uploading document itself.

So, I use updateDocument API without "File" parameter to update metadata only, but unfortunately enrich data is gone. (metadata is successfully updated!).

Is this updatedocument api's spec?
If I want to update metadata. Do I need upload document itself?

https://watson-api-explorer.ng.bluemix.net/apis/discovery-v1#!/Documents/updateDocument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Discovery does not support updating only the metadata.

As you speculate, you do need to re-upload the document itself, along with the new or updated metadata that you want.

[This documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/curl.html?curl#update-document) says:

> **Update a document**
>
> Replace an existing document. Starts ingesting a document with optional metadata.

which I can see may not be completely clear. By saying *Replace an existing document* it is trying to convey that the existing document is **always** and **completely** replaced.